# How to store DMA buffer array?

Tags: adc, stm32, dma

I am trying to store DMA buffer array such as below;

////////////////////Global Area;////////////////////////////////////////

```
uint16_t ADC_Vbatt=0;
uint16_t ADC_buffer[2];
```

/////////////////main function/////////////////////////////////////////

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Vbat_Meas_En_GPIO_Port,Vbat_Meas_En_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);

HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc, (uint32_t*)ADC_buffer,2);

ADC_Vbatt = ADC_buffer[1];

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Vbat_Meas_En_GPIO_Port,Vbat_Meas_En_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```

but when I look in debug mode, `ADC_Vbatt` variable is empty. I do not understand why.

So, how to store `ADC_buffer[2]` array in two variable?

Comment: Is this an STM32?

Comment: If the function name suggest meaninfully, you just  *start* the DMA transfer. You never wait for it to finish before reading the target.

Comment: -DiBosco -> Yes, this is STM32L011K4

-Marcus  -> I do not fully understand.  Could you please explain detailed?

Comment: you just started the DMA copy process. You don't wait for the copy to finish.

Comment: So normally values are being recorded, but I can not notice it in debug mode. Is it true?